# overlay two images in android to set an imageview

Tags: android, image

I am trying to overlay two images in my app, but they seem to crash at my `canvas.setBitmap()` line. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void test() {
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.t);
    Bitmap mBitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tt);
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBitmap(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap2, new Matrix(), null);
    testimage.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);
}
```

Comment: Can use a framelayout as well, like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11658554/586484

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You can skip the complex Canvas manipulation and do this entirely with Drawables, using [`LayerDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html).  You have one of two choices: You can either [define it in XML](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#layer-list) then simply set the image, or you can configure a `LayerDrawable` dynamically in code.

Solution #1 (via XML):

Create a new Drawable XML file, let's call it `layer.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/t" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tt" />
</layer-list>
```

Now set the image using that Drawable:

```
testimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.layer));
```

Solution #2 (dynamic):

```
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.t);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.tt);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
testimage.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

(I haven't tested this code so there may be a mistake, but this general outline should work.)

Comment: thank you, it worked!

one typo though, in case someone else uses the code: 
LayerDrawable layers2 = new LayerDrawable(layers);
testimage.setImageDrawable(layers2);

Comment: Great way to save space and reuse images. Also, you can use the android:left, android:right, android:top and android:down to control the position of one of the layers in the .xml file.

Comment: I used this to draw a circular shape drawable behind an image, very nice solution!

Comment: Is there a way to hide the layers[1] alone programmatically? I want to show an Image layer with ajax loader layer on top. After some time I want to hide the ajax loader alone. Any suggestion?

Comment: I found this solution not very useful. It seems to be more work to get the layers scaled... I don't find any solution. :-/

Comment: Works well for my needs (I used the code approach). I have a number of 'tiles' which the user taps on to navigate around the app. Using this approach I was able to have a single background image (common to all tiles) and numerous foreground images (with transparent backgrounds) which i can load at runtime. Would not have looked at the LayerDrawable without this answer :-)

Answer (score 10):

ok just so you know there is a program out there that's called DroidDraw. It can help you draw objects and try them one on top of the other. I tried your solution but I had animation under the smaller image so that didn't work. But then I tried to place one image in a relative layout that's suppose to be under first and then on top of that I drew the other image that is suppose to overlay and everything worked great. So RelativeLayout, DroidDraw and you are good to go :) Simple, no any kind of jiggery pockery :) and here is a bit of code for ya:

The logo is going to be on top of shazam background image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/widget39"
android:layout_width="219px"
android:layout_height="225px"
android:src="@drawable/shazam_bkgd"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
</ImageView>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/widget37"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/shazam_logo"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Create two functions to handle each.

First, the  canvas is drawn and the images are drawn on top of each other from point (0,0)

On button click

```
public void buttonMerge(View view) {

        Bitmap bigImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
        Bitmap smallImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img2);
        Bitmap mergedImages = createSingleImageFromMultipleImages(bigImage, smallImage);

        img.setImageBitmap(mergedImages);
    }
```

Function to create an overlay.

```
private Bitmap createSingleImageFromMultipleImages(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage){

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(firstImage.getWidth(), firstImage.getHeight(), firstImage.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(firstImage, 0f, 0f, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(secondImage, 10, 10, null);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit late answer, but it covers merging images from urls using Picasso

**MergeImageView**

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MergeImageView extends ImageView {

    private SparseArray<Bitmap> bitmaps = new SparseArray<>();
    private Picasso picasso;
    private final int DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = 50;
    private int MIN_IMAGE_SIZE = DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE;
    private int MAX_WIDTH = DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE * 2, MAX_HEIGHT = DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE * 2;
    private String picassoRequestTag = null;

    public MergeImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MergeImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MergeImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MergeImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInEditMode() {
        return true;
    }

    public void clearResources() {
        if (bitmaps != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.size(); i++)
                bitmaps.get(i).recycle();
            bitmaps.clear();
        }
        // cancel picasso requests
        if (picasso != null && AppUtils.ifNotNullEmpty(picassoRequestTag))
            picasso.cancelTag(picassoRequestTag);
        picasso = null;
        bitmaps = null;
    }

    public void createMergedBitmap(Context context, List<String> imageUrls, String picassoTag) {
        picasso = Picasso.with(context);
        int count = imageUrls.size();
        picassoRequestTag = picassoTag;

        boolean isEven = count % 2 == 0;
        // if url size are not even make MIN_IMAGE_SIZE even
        MIN_IMAGE_SIZE = DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE + (isEven ? count / 2 : (count / 2) + 1);
        // set MAX_WIDTH and MAX_HEIGHT to twice of MIN_IMAGE_SIZE
        MAX_WIDTH = MAX_HEIGHT = MIN_IMAGE_SIZE * 2;
        // in case of odd urls increase MAX_HEIGHT
        if (!isEven) MAX_HEIGHT = MAX_WIDTH + MIN_IMAGE_SIZE;

        // create default bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_wallpaper),
                MIN_IMAGE_SIZE, MIN_IMAGE_SIZE, false);

        // change default height (wrap_content) to MAX_HEIGHT
        int height = Math.round(AppUtils.convertDpToPixel(MAX_HEIGHT, context));
        setMinimumHeight(height * 2);

        // start AsyncTask
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            // put default bitmap as a place holder
            bitmaps.put(index, bitmap);
            new PicassoLoadImage(index, imageUrls.get(index)).execute();
            // if you want parallel execution use
            // new PicassoLoadImage(index, imageUrls.get(index)).(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    }

    private class PicassoLoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        private int index = 0;
        private String url;

        PicassoLoadImage(int index, String url) {
            this.index = index;
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                // synchronous picasso call
                return picasso.load(url).resize(MIN_IMAGE_SIZE, MIN_IMAGE_SIZE).tag(picassoRequestTag).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap output) {
            super.onPostExecute(output);
            if (output != null)
                bitmaps.put(index, output);

            // create canvas
            Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, conf);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            // if height and width are equal we have even images
            boolean isEven = MAX_HEIGHT == MAX_WIDTH;
            int imageSize = bitmaps.size();
            int count = imageSize;

            // we have odd images
            if (!isEven) count = imageSize - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps.get(i);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth() * (i % 2), bitmap.getHeight() * (i / 2), null);
            }
            // if images are not even set last image width to MAX_WIDTH
            if (!isEven) {
                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps.get(count), MAX_WIDTH, MIN_IMAGE_SIZE, false);
                canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, scaledBitmap.getWidth() * (count % 2), scaledBitmap.getHeight() * (count / 2), null);
            }
            // set bitmap
            setImageBitmap(canvasBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<com.example.MergeImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_thumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Example**

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
String picassoTag = null;
// add your urls
((MergeImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_thumb)).
        createMergedBitmap(MainActivity.this, urls,picassoTag);
```

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution:

```
    public Bitmap Blend(Bitmap topImage1, Bitmap bottomImage1, PorterDuff.Mode Type) {

        Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(topImage1);
        Bitmap topImage = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Bitmap workingBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bottomImage1);
        Bitmap bottomImage = workingBitmap2.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, bottomImage.getWidth(), bottomImage.getHeight());
        new BitmapFactory.Options().inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bottomImage.setHasAlpha(true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bottomImage);
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Type));

        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(topImage, null, dest, paint);
        return bottomImage;
    }
```

usage :

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Blend(topBitmap, bottomBitmap, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
```

or

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Blend(topBitmap, bottomBitmap, PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY));
```

and the results :

Overlay mode :
[image: Overlay mode]

Screen mode:
[image: Screen mode]

Comment: It's good. But if want to display two images near what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin:**

Let `imageView1` be the first image, `imageView2` be the second image and `resultImageView` be the result image, in which you can generate embedded image of `imageView1` and `imageView2`.

```
        val layers = arrayOfNulls<Drawable>(2)
        layers[0] = imageView1.drawable
        layers[1] = imageView2.drawable
        val layerDrawable = LayerDrawable(layers)
        resultImageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable)
```