# Draw images on top of each other in android

Tags: android, image

I have some images that I want to put on top of each other on random order.

If it possible using one ImageView or do I need to create multiple image views based on number of images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't completely specify what you want.... if you want the images to be placed in different positions (in the X and Y axis), meaning that while watching the photo on the top you can see part of the other images, then you have to create different `ImageViews`, or drawing them on a canvas (I think this one is much better).

If the images are just one on top of the other (hiding the one on the bottom),  you just have to use one `ImageView`.

Comment: yeah I want to see other images also.Looks like I need to create different Imageviews .

Comment: But why you have mentioned that drawing on canvas is better option.

Comment: Because you won't have to created many ImageViews, and also you can do fancy effects easily (like rotating the photos, so that they look really disorganized).

Answer (score 1):

LayerDrawable may fit your requirement, you may refer to this post [overlay two images in android to set an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview/2740198#2740198)