# Android: Setting padding in a overlay image background

Tags: android, image, overlay, padding

I'm trying to create a dynamic icon menu for my android application.
The icon is made from 2 drawable, a 9-patch background image with the icon image overlay on it.

With reference to [overlay two images in android to set an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview), I've the following code which have the overlay nicely.

```
        Resources res = parent.getResources();
        Drawable icon_bg = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_icon_bg);
        Drawable icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_icon);

        // Not working
        int int_icon_height = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int int_icon_width = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
        Rect rect_icon_bg_bound = new Rect();
        rect_icon_bg_bound.left = 0;//(int) Math.round(int_icon_width*-1.5);
        rect_icon_bg_bound.right = (int) Math.round(int_icon_width*1.5);
        rect_icon_bg_bound.top = 0;//(int)Math.round(int_icon_height*-1.5);
        rect_icon_bg_bound.bottom = (int)Math.round(int_icon_height*1.5);
        icon_bg.setBounds(rect_icon_bg_bound);

        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = icon_bg;
        layers[1] = icon;

        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        ImageView iv_icon_combined = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv_icon_combined.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

The problem I'm facing right now is adding a padding so that the icon will have some spacing within the background.

Hope to get some enlightenment here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm still stuck on this question. Is there some other place I can look into to help in this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue. Take a look at the [setLayerInset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerInset%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method on LayerDrawable. It takes the layer level as an argument and then the modifiers for the left, top, right, bottom bounds of the drawable.