# Android : set background of layout using image path

Tags: android, background, drawable, resource-id

I want to put an image as background of a **Layout**.

First I am creating a drawable : `Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("pathToImageFile");`

In **API level 8**  `layout.setBackground( d )` is **not supported** AND    `layout.setBackgroundDrawable( d )` **is deprecated**  so I need to use

`layout.setBackgroundResource(resourceID)`

how can I get resourceID of a dynamically generated drawable.I am using this method :

`Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("pathToImageFile");`

to create a drawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi use the following method

```
public void setBackgroundDrawable (Drawable background)
```

by calling

```
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Added in API level 1

EDIT:
try this method

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void setRes(ImageView iv,Drawable drawable){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            iv.setBackground(drawable);
        else
            iv.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

Comment: This method is deprecated can I use it ?? In eclipse it is showing with a strike in code.

Comment: this method is depricated in api level 16 up to API level 15 it will work grt

Comment: Thanks alot. I was also thinking of this method. But still the strike mark in eclipse is not going away. even after using   `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` and `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`

Comment: it will show strike make because you may have updated the android sdk above 15 level so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBackground(Drawable background)` method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Comment: Problem remains same. It also uses API level 16.

Comment: Use setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) from API level 1

Comment: It is deprecated so can't use now.

Comment: It's deprecated in API level 16. So you can use this. If you use API 16 or above use setBackground method.

Answer (score 0):

For API 1-15 use

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

For API 16 & above use

```
viw.setBackground(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637063/how-to-get-android-resource-id-from-dynamically-created-in-java-layer-list-l) by @hasanghaforian,

You can get the resource ID using the "**getIdentifier**" with the following code:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("org.anddev.android.testproject:drawable/bug", null, null);
```

OR

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("bug", "drawable", "org.anddev.android.testproject");
```

where,

`bug.png` is the file in "`/res/drawable/`".

Then you can use `layout.setBackgroundResource(resID)`.

Comment: as we are dynamically creating **drawable** we don't know it's name, which in this case is "bug".