# put a logo on a photo taken with phone camera!

Tags: android, photo

I have an android application which allows the user to take a picture using the phone camera.
Further more I want to edit the photo that I've taken.I don't wanna do complicated operations on it, just something predifened.Some kind of logo at the bottom of the picture!!

Can someone point me in the right direction,please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the camera class to take a picture. There is a detailed explanation on how to use it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html):

To take pictures using `Camera` class, do the following steps:

1. Obtain an instance of `Camera` from `open(int)`.
2. Get existing (default) settings with `getParameters()`.
3. If necessary, modify the returned Camera.Parameters object and call `setParameters(Camera.Parameters)`.
4. If desired, call `setDisplayOrientation(int)`.
5. Important: Pass a fully initialized SurfaceHolder to `setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder)`. Without a surface, the camera will be unable to start the preview.
6. Important: Call `startPreview()` to start updating the preview surface. Preview must be started before you can take a picture.
7. When you want, call `takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback)` to capture a photo. Wait for the callbacks to provide the actual image data.
8. After taking a picture, preview display will have stopped. To take more photos, call `startPreview()` again first.
9. Call `stopPreview()` to stop updating the preview surface.
10. Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in `onPause()` (and re-open() it in `onResume()`).

`takePicuture` will give you a jpeg image and then  you can add your watermark. For that look into  `Canvas.drawBitmap` with alpha channel.

Comment: I was asking for some answer like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview

Comment: I started the camera using an intent.Though the pictures taken are displayed horizontally!Do you know how could I fix that?

Comment: Maybe this can help" `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29`