# How can I set the background of an android layout to a color plus an image?

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I have a png with transparency that I'd like to use for the background of my layout.  I need to set the background of the layout to a color, and then draw the image on top of that.  Things I'd rather not do:

1. Create a layout within my layout.  Set the background of the outer layout to the color, set the background of the inner layout to the bitmap.  This actually generates a warning because the inner layout doesn't do anything.
2. Don't use a transparent png, just render the background image with the color.

Can I create an xml drawable that contains the image and the color maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a layer-list drawable,

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Here's another post on the topic,

> [overlay two images in android to set an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), in which you place your Color as an XML Drawble on the bottom, and then your other below that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can define a drawable that is made of multiple other drawables in xml: A [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)