# Android: Using multiple images over eachother in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is it possible to have multiple images over eachother in android with xml in the layout file, like say you have one background image and when the user presses a button it adds another picture above the background?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you

[overlay two images in android to set an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview)

It uses [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html).