# Highlighting and selecting parts of an image Android?

Tags: java, android, highlight

I'm trying to figure out how to just highlight certain parts of an image for android. I'll do more once I can highlight the certain part of the image, but I can't seem to figure this out.

For example, I have an image of the human body. I just want to be able to select a part of it, such as the brain, arm, stomach, heart, etc. I'm using a image found online from a png file, let me know if it's better to create an image using java.drawable or if I can just work with the downloaded image.

What is the best way to go about this in Java? The only way I can think of is replacing the image with another selected one, but I don't want to have to handle 20 different images.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to overlay a highlight color or a highlight image by using the methods described at [overlay two images in android to set an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview)

Comment: No problem. If you want you can click on the check mark next to the question in order to accept an answer. Welcome to stackoverflow!