# Android Best way to overlay an item in an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, overlay

Any ideas on how to overlay a View over an ImageView?
More specifically I would like to popover view when the user clicks in certain regions of my ImageView.
I'm solving this problem drawing the popover view after the image in the onDraw() method but it has been a pain to handle events when the user clicks in the popover.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FrameLayout` resolves this problem. You can place two children inside the `FrameLayout`, where the first child will be the background and the second will be the foreground. Let your `ImageView` be in background, then you can place any other `View` and it will overlay the `ImageView`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I position the popover element? with padding?

Comment: @lfrodrigues, It's recommended that you use android:layout_gravity, but surely you can use android:padding and android:layout_margin to achieve a better effect.

Answer (score 1):

for overlaying views, you can wrap them in a FrameLayout. add first the ImaveView to it, then the overlay view.