# Android View background: How to specify background color for PNG transparency?

Tags: android, android-layout, background, android-linearlayout, transparent

I want my Android View's background to be the logo on a white background.

I can make my View's background white:

```
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
```

I can make my View's background a PNG:

```
android:background="@drawable/logo"
```

But not both at the same time (`Attribute "android:background" was already specified`).
If I write only `@drawable/logo` then the logo is drawn on a black background.
How to do? Preferably without adding a layer of view.

---

**SOLUTION:** I used Avinazz's first suggestion, and here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

With `strings.xml` containing `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several possibilities:

1) Use [Layer drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) or [overlay two images in android to set an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview)

2) Tweak your xml to have container background to have white backgroud, and child with your desired image with transperancy.

3) Edit the image to have white background.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own theme or use inbuilt Light theme in your manifest file inside your activity tag, and then use your background in layout xml. `android:background="@drawable/logo`