# Recommended way to display background image on Android

Tags: android

What is the recommended approach to displaying a background image (or border) on Android. The foreground will be photos my users can specify. See below, the gray area will be the user-defined photos in the foreground:

[image]

I see the following possibilities:

1. [Overlaying two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview)
2. Create a 9-patch image from the background and defining it as the background to the imageview that will display the photos.

The photos will be fixed-sized so I'm leaning towards option 1. Any recommendations from folks who have had to do this type of thing before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the record, I actually ended up going with option #2 because it provided me the most flexibility. And creating the 9-patch image wasn't much trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had to do exactly this (but a little more complex since everything was rotated and skrewed) and the best solution for us to use your mentioned overlaying images, because it can be done through xml (in your case) which is better to maintain. 9-Patches are also great but take more time to create and edit.