# Merge two image

Tags: android, image, merge

I want merge two images and shows these over the map. I used `boundCenterBottom()` method for add image on the map. I want second image set on top of first image. like below image:

[image]

red circle is, second image and i want to set on top and center from first image. 
I searched and i read for merge i should use canvas and bitmap. I used these but not work like this.

Thanks for advise

Comment: Just put both images in a FrameLayout and then show the layout on top of the map.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but i should write this programatically. and this is not another way?

Comment: You can create a FrameLayout programatically if that is what you're asking.

Comment: and another way instead of create FrameLayout? Can i use Bitmap and canvas for create this? like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview?rq=1

Comment: Why do you need to create a Bitmap and Canvas? As the answer in the link states, it will just make things complex. Why don't you use something simple like the layer XML stated in the answer? By the way, what are trying to achieve exactly? Can you paste your code?