# How to custom switch button?

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, android-switch

I am looking to Custom The `Switch` Button to becoming as following :

[image]

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

However, I might not be taking the best approach, but this is how I have created some `Switch` like UIs in few of my apps.
Here is the code -

```
<RadioGroup
        android:checkedButton="@+id/offer"
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/pink_out_line"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_widget_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/offer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_widget_background"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Offers"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

pink_out_line.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#80000000" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/pink" />
</shape>
```

toggle_widget_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/pink" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/dark_pink" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And here is the output -[image]

Comment: This worked fantastic. The only modification I also made was adding android:textColor to the selector and applying that to the radio buttons text. Then I could have white text on the selected item and black text on the non-selected item.

Comment: I added  android:textColor like below
<item android:drawable="@color/textcolorwhite" android:state_pressed="true" android:textColor="#BDBDBD" />

and removed android:textColor="@color/white" from radio button but radio button text color is not changing

Comment: I think you should use the "android:state_checked"

Comment: That's Awesome. I was getting confused between toggle button and switch button and Radio button. And after getting your solution now i am confirmed with radio button.

Comment: Will it have the switch-like toggle animation?

Comment: Is there a way to show a sliding animation when we switch from one state to another?

Comment: The correct Answer is here. to customize the switch buttons.
https://youtu.be/5xMPLe1gnOA

Answer (score 58):

Its a simple xml design. It looks like iOS switch, check this below image

[image]

You need to create custom_thumb.xml and custom_track.xml

This is my switch,I need a very big switch so added layout_width/layout_height parameter

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/swOnOff"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:showText="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
        app:track="@drawable/custom_track"
        android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_120sdp"/>
```

Now create custom_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <size android:width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_100sdp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#8c8c8c"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <size android:width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_100sdp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#34c759"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now create custom_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_100sdp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke android:color="#8c8c8c" android:width="1dp"/>
            <size android:height="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_100sdp" />
            <solid android:color="#34c759" />
            <stroke android:color="#8c8c8c" android:width="1dp"/>
            <size android:height="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Coud you provide you dimen file?

Comment: @ArpitPatel that dimen file is coming from this dependency add this into your gradle file & boom that error will be gone ----- just copy * paste it  *implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'*

Comment: Yes, but Here is what you need to customize the switch buttons.
https://youtu.be/5xMPLe1gnOA

Comment: Excellent. very nice

Answer (score 25):

you can use the following code to change **color** and **text** :

```
<org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch
                        android:id="@+id/th"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:thumb="@drawable/apptheme_switch_inner_holo_light"
                        app:track="@drawable/apptheme_switch_track_holo_light"
                        app:textOn="@string/switch_yes"
                        app:textOff="@string/switch_no"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        />
```

Create a xml named colors.xml in res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

In drawable folder, create a xml file my_btn_toggle.xml:

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/red"  />
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/green"  />
    </selector>
```

and in xml section defining your toggle button add:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_btn_toggle
```

to change the color of `textOn` and `textOff`use

```
android:switchTextAppearance="@style/Switch"
```

Comment: Btw, if anyone has issues with XML errors (unbound tag prefix), make sure you add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to the top of the layout sheet. It will let you use the `app:` prefix.

Comment: quick appproach!! but i like to add few points here as when using this way 
put thumb and track attributes in xml to @null.

Answer (score 22):

```
<Switch android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/custom_switch_inner_holo_light"
                    android:track="@drawable/custom_switch_track_holo_light"
                    android:textOn="@string/yes"
                    android:textOff="@string/no"/>
```

drawable/custom_switch_inner_holo_light.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_switch_thumb_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/custom_switch_thumb_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/custom_switch_thumb_activated_holo_light" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/custom_switch_thumb_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

drawable/custom_switch_track_holo_light.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/custom_switch_bg_focused_holo_light" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/custom_switch_bg_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

Next images are 9.paths drawables and they must be in different density (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi). As example I give xxhdpi (you can resize they if u needed):

drawable/custom_switch_thumb_disabled_holo_light

[image: custom_switch_thumb_disabled_holo_light]

drawable/custom_switch_thumb_pressed_holo_light

[image: custom_switch_thumb_pressed_holo_light]

drawable/custom_switch_thumb_activated_holo_light

[image: custom_switch_thumb_activated_holo_light]

drawable/custom_switch_thumb_holo_light

[image: custom_switch_thumb_holo_light]

drawable/custom_switch_bg_focused_holo_light

[image: custom_switch_bg_focused_holo_light]

drawable/custom_switch_bg_holo_light

[image]

Comment: It doesn't show both text. It still only shows selected text.

Answer (score 17):

I achieved this

[image]

by doing:

1) custom selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_switch_off"
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_switch_on"
          android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

2) using v7 SwitchCompat

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_yura"
    android:thumb="@null"
    app:track="@null"/>
```

Comment: this makes the button to the start of the view. What if the button needs to be placed at the end of the Switch (after the text of the switch)

Comment: @TarunKumar have you got something for aligning layout in the center?

Answer (score 17):

I use this approach to create a custom switch using a `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton`;

### Preview

[image]

### Color Resource

```
<color name="blue">#FF005a9c</color>
<color name="lightBlue">#ff6691c4</color>
<color name="lighterBlue">#ffcdd8ec</color>
<color name="controlBackground">#ffffffff</color>
```

**control_switch_color_selector** (in res/color folder)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/controlBackground"
    />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/controlBackground"
        />
    <item
        android:color="@color/blue"
        />
</selector>
```

### Drawables

**control_switch_background_border.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/blue" />
</shape>
```

**control_switch_background_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/blue"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/lighterBlue"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**control_switch_background_selector_middle.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/blue"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/lighterBlue"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:top="-1dp" android:bottom="-1dp" android:left="-1dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"></solid>
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/blue"></stroke>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

### Layout

```
<RadioGroup
        android:checkedButton="@+id/calm"
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/control_switch_background_border"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/calm"
            android:background="@drawable/control_switch_background_selector_middle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Calm"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="@color/control_switch_color_selector"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/rumor"
            android:background="@drawable/control_switch_background_selector_middle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Rumor"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="@color/control_switch_color_selector"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/outbreak"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/control_switch_background_selector"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Outbreak"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="@color/control_switch_color_selector" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: It was quite useful

Answer (score 14):

Use the code below to create a custom switch button like the one shown below.

[image]

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:checked="false"
        app:track="@drawable/track"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
        android:text="" />
```

**@drawable/track**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF3333"/>
            <corners android:radius="100sp"/>
            <stroke android:color="#8e8e8e"
                android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_green"/>      <!--color name="color_green">#3bd391</color-->
            <corners android:radius="100sp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**@drawable/thumb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_false"/>

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_true"/>

</selector>
```

**@drawable/switch_thumb_false**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <size android:height="3dp"
                android:width="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_16"
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

**@drawable/switch_thumb_true**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <size android:height="3dp"
                android:width="3dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1sp"
                android:color="#8e8e8e" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_correct_16"
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        />


</layer-list>
```

**@drawable/ic_baseline_correct_16**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="16dp"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="#008F28"
    android:alpha="0.9">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M9,16.2L4.8,12l-1.4,1.4L9,19 21,7l-1.4,-1.4L9,16.2z"/>
</vector>
```

**@drawable/ic_baseline_close_16**

```
<vector
    android:height="16dp"
    android:tint="#FF0000"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="16dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: app:useMaterialThemeColors="false" is required when you use SwitchMaterial

Answer (score 7):

You can use Android Material Components.

[image]

build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

layout.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:checkedButton="@id/btn_one_way"
        app:singleSelection="true">

    <Button
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:id="@+id/btn_one_way"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="One way trip" />

    <Button
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:id="@+id/btn_round"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Round trip" />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Example 1:**

[image: off]
[image: on]

**custom_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <size android:width="37dp" android:height="37dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <size android:width="37dp" android:height="37dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**custom_track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    android:visible="true"
    android:dither="true"
    android:useLevel="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"/>
    <size
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="26dp" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/white"
        android:width="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
            android:track="@drawable/custom_track"
            tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Example 2:**

[image: off]

[image: on]

**custom_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
            <size android:width="37dp" android:height="37dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
            <size android:width="37dp" android:height="37dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**custom_track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    android:visible="true"
    android:dither="true"
    android:useLevel="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"/>
    <size
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="26dp" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/white"
        android:width="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
            android:track="@drawable/custom_track"
            tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Example 3:**

[image: off]

[image: on]

**custom_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size android:width="37dp" android:height="37dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size android:width="37dp" android:height="37dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#cdcdcd" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**custom_track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <size android:width="50dp" android:height="26dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
           <solid android:color="#cdcdcd" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <size android:width="50dp" android:height="26dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#EDEDED"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/custom_track"
        tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the regular Switch widget and just call `setTextOn()` and `setTextOff()`, or use the `android:textOn` and `android:textOff` attributes.

Comment: how can i change the text color of textOn & textOff ?

Comment: with the `android:textColor` attribute. If on and off need different colors, you will need to make a color state list: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: android:textColor change the color of android:text

Comment: This is wrong. The textOn and TextOff for the text of the thumb.

Answer (score 3):

With the Material Components Library you can use the [**`MaterialButtonToggleGroup`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#toggle-button):

```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:checkedButton="@id/b1"
            app:selectionRequired="true"
            app:singleSelection="true">

            <Button
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OPT1" />

            <Button
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OPT2" />

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: This toggle button produces `inflate` error for my project when I put it into fragment layout.

Answer (score 1):

More info on this link: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_me"/>
```

and the drawable will be something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_me_on" /> <!-- checked -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_me_off" /> <!-- default/unchecked -->
</selector>
```

Comment: the link is broken :(

Comment: Sorry may be that web domain expired.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create custom ToggleButton

1) By defining custom background
2) By creating custom button

Check http://www.zoftino.com/android-toggle-button for custom styles

**Toggle button with custom background**

Define drawable as xml resource like below and set it as background of toggle button. In the below example, drawable toggle_color is a color selector, you need to define this also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="4dp"
    android:insetTop="4dp"
    android:insetRight="4dp"
    android:insetBottom="4dp">
    <layer-list android:paddingMode="stack">
        <item>
            <ripple android:color="?attr/android:colorControlHighlight">
                <item>
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
                        android:tint="?attr/android:colorButtonNormal">
                        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
                        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                        <padding android:left="8dp"
                            android:top="6dp"
                            android:right="8dp"
                            android:bottom="6dp" />
                    </shape>
                </item>
            </ripple>
        </item>
        <item android:gravity="left|fill_vertical">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
                <size android:width="8dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/toggle_color" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:gravity="right|fill_vertical">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
                <size android:width="8dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/toggle_color" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</inset>
```

**Toggle button with custom button**

Create your own images for two state of toggle button (make sure images exist for all sizes of screens) and place them in drawable folder, create selector and set it as button.

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

### switch

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     app:track="@drawable/track"
     android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
     android:id="@+id/switch1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

### thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_false"/>

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_true"/>

</selector>
```

### track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <size android:width="24dp" android:height="12dp" />
            <solid android:color="#EFE0BB" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="true">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <size android:width="24dp" android:height="12dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

### switch_thumb_true.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#EFE0BB" />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

### switch_thumb_false.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <size android:height="12dp"
                android:width="12dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="#EFE0BB"
                android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: This ain't reliable

Comment: But Why? Do you apply this code?

Comment: Yes. Check what OP wants!

Comment: Okay, I will check.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Switch
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/track"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image]

[image]