# How to display switch widget with image in android?

Tags: android, material-design

Kindly help me to create switch widget in android with images that can be change on it's state change.

It should be something like this: [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button

Comment: In above link, there are labels. I want to display image instead of labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as below. It is an edited version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button)

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/th"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:textOff="@string/switch_no"
    app:textOn="@string/switch_yes"
    app:thumb="@drawable/apptheme_switch_inner_holo_light"
    app:track="@drawable/apptheme_switch_track_holo_light" />
```

In drawable folder, create a xml file my_btn_toggle.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/red"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/green"/>
</selector>
```

where red and green are your desired images.

and in xml section defining your toggle button add:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_btn_toggle
```

Hope this helps you.