# Android - How to reduce custom drawable size programmatically without affecting its quality?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-drawable, custom-component

I need to create a custom `switch` using drawable elements (custom thumb and custom track). I tried several sizes (50x50, 70x70, 100x100) and they all appear out of proportion, unless I use 25x25 icons which look pixelated. How do I scale-down these elements to an appropriate size without lowering its quality?

For example, this is the way it looks now:
[image]

This is my `switch`

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="10dip"
    android:id="@+id/switcSound"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:track="@drawable/switch_track"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:switchMinWidth="55dp"
   />
```

This is my `switch` `thumb` xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: try with 9 patch image..see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button

Comment: 9patch can stretch icons and images, but I need to scale down the already (relatively) big icons, or am I missing something?

Comment: you should just open the original image in some tools like paint.net and work them to get the correct sizes you need : hdpi, xhdpi etc.