# Android switch custom left-right drawables

Tags: android, android-switch

I'm trying to create a custom switch like this:

[image: custom gender switch]

What I feel like I need is something like a left/right drawable each in a green/white state, or alternatively a green outline with a drawable for when the choice should be selected.

What I don't understand in posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch) is how all the sample drawables provided slant to the right, and yet the 'on' button slants to the left.

I'm trying with the following 'thumb' drawable.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/choice_right"/>
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/choice_left"/>
</selector>
```

but it seems to cut the ends off the drawables. If I also set a track to something like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <stroke 
            android:width="1dp" 
            android:color="@color/text_input"/>

        <corners
            android:radius="1dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="4.5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="4.5dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="4.5dp"
            android:topRightRadius="4.5dp" >
    </corners>
</shape>
```

then all I get is a thin line. So, I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This cannot be with styling alone, this needs custom view implementation. Thats lot of code so my suggestion for you would be to use 3rd party libraries like
https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control 
This library is tried and tested so its safe to use it instead of rewriting it.

Comment: So, perhaps the answer is that this isn't a particularly Android-oriented design and that the design needs to change to fit more with Android's UI elements

Comment: This design is derived from iOS, but the new SwitchCompat widget looks as good and simple as this widget, so give it a try .

Answer (score 6):

I have created an example app that you can find [here](https://github.com/NeilHogg69/Android-Tutorials/tree/master/CustomSwitch) that should solve your problem. You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control) library that has a proper implementation of the segment control.

Basically I created a custom control that extends `LinearLayout` with a default `weightSum` of 2. Two `Buttons` are added with a `weight` of 1 and some logic is applied to toggle between them. On toggle an custom event is fired that is built on this interface.

```
public interface SwitchToggleListener {
    void onSwitchToggle(SwitchToggleState switchToggleState);
}
```

I used `drawable` resources to style the buttons.

The final result looked like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can used RadioGroup with two RadioButton:

```
<RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/male_radio_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_radio_btn_text"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_radio_btn_left_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="@string/male_radio_text"
                    />

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/female_radio_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_radio_btn_text"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_radio_btn_right_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:text="@string/female_radio_text"/>
        </RadioGroup>
```

where selector_radio_btn_text.xml is text color selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/checkbox_text_color_checked"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/checkbox_text_color"/>
```

and selector_radio_btn_left_bg(right bg).xml is backgorund of left and right side

Answer (score 1):

Instead of his using any external libaray or support library this can be done easily by using RadioGroup and radio buttons. As "Dimitry " has mentioned in his answer I too have used the same thing to achieve.
Here is the copy paste of my answer given for the question [How to custom switch button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button/33231991#33231991)

```
  <RadioGroup
    android:checkedButton="@+id/offer"
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:background="@drawable/pink_out_line"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_widget_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/offer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_widget_background"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Offers"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RadioGroup>
```

pink_out_line.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="2dp" />
<solid android:color="#80000000" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/pink" />
</shape>
```

toggle_widget_background.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"         standalone="no"?>
      <selector        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@color/pink" android:state_checked="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@color/dark_pink" android:state_pressed="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update answer**

to do this you should create layer-list in drawable folder

**res/drawable/toggle_layerlist.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/choice_right">
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="@color/text_input"/>

    <corners
        android:radius="1dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4.5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4.5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4.5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4.5dp" >
    </corners>
</shape>
    </item>

    </layer-list>
```

add layer list to your selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_layerlist" android:state_checked="true"  />

    </selector>
```

use this selector as background , but make sure you empty text in on/off state

by set  `android:textOff=""  android:textOn=""`

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/chkState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>
```

do the same to other state