# Why Switch button does not show text?

Tags: android, android-switch

I create a Switch button this way:

```
            Switch sw = new Switch(activity);
            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ll = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ll.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            sw.setLayoutParams(ll);
            sw.setTextOn("OK");
            sw.setTextOff("NOK");
            layout.addView(sw);
```

The switch appears, but with no text. Furthermore, I want the style to be like as this URL: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/form_elements/togglebutton/

How can I achieve all of this?
Thanks

EDIT:

I have get this switch button, which is ugly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the text to be shown:

`sw.setShowText(true)`

Comment: Yes, but I had to increase API Level first. However, the style is very ugly, as shown in the picture I uploaded to the question... is there a way to make it prettier?

Answer (score 0):

To style your switch, you can see: [How to custom switch button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button)

Maybe you should change the `track` and `thumb` drawable