# Android Switch Button Custom design

Tags: android, android-switch

I am developing an app that can post two kinds of questions. to switch views i need a switch button on the TOP. i need help to customize my switch button like following image.

[image: Switch Button]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to custom switch button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button)

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button and also http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-use-and-custom-switch-in-android.html

Comment: thanks for you reply. thanks

Comment: @RonakMakwana did you try my answer?

Comment: i a looking at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below gihub library for this type of button

https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton

Advantage:

- customize as per color you want
- with good animation of switching button