# How to create Facebook Messenger like buttons for MESSENGER\ACTIVE Fragment, and how to swap fragments using them?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-messenger

I'd like to know how MESSENGER\ACTIVE button configuration is achieved...

And if switching fragments on button click will work with this configuration..?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by customizing a `RadioGroup` with two `RadioButton` as child.

Here is some hints-

### Steps can be like this

1. Create a `drawable` `shape` of type rectangle in `xml` with corner and stroke. Use it for the `RadioGroup` background.
2. Create `selector` using the similar shapes (for color as per selected and un-selected one)for two `RadioButon`  and set them as individual background.
3. Create one `color` `drawable` in xml for selected and un-selected states and set its as textColor to the `RadioButton`
4. Set `android:button`attribute of `RadioButton` to null.
   Here is an example which i have posted as answer to an SO question - [How to custom switch button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button/33231991#33231991)