# Custom switchcompat with different images for states

Tags: android, custom-controls, switchcompat

Developing  application with List and Map data  presentations. For  switching between presentations  should  be  used custom  switch with  images, like  this:

[image]

How to  create such custom switchcompat?

Comment: How did you achieve this? can you share your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is very good example:

[ORIGINAL ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33231991/3735097)

You can define the drawables that are used for the background, and the switcher part like this:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/switch_bg" />
```

Now you need to create a selector that defines the different states for the switcher drawable.
Here the copies from the Android sources:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

This defines the thumb drawable, the image that is moved over the background. There are four   [ninepatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) images used for the slider:

The deactivated version (xhdpi version that Android is using)
[image: The deactivated version]
The pressed slider:
[image: The pressed slider]
The activated slider (on state):
[image: The activated slider]
The default version (off state): 
[image]

There are also three different states for the background that are defined in the following selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_disabled_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

The deactivated version: 
[image: The deactivated version]
The focused version: 
[image: The focused version]
And the default version:
[image: the default version]

To have a styled switch just create this two selectors, set them to your Switch View and then change the seven images to your desired style.

Comment: thank  you  for  answer!  but  this control  should be  like SwitchCompat  (not  like  radio  button) -   should  change  status  when  user  pulling  it  left to  right and  vice  versa