# Changing the background color of a Switch

Tags: android, android-switch

[image]

I've tried using android:background="@color/colorWhite"/> but it changes the entire background of the switch not that small grey part.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
          
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

[image]

`android:backgroundTint` doesn't do anything either

Comment: This should give you an idea on how to solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button/58890218

Comment: @Richmahnn Thanks! I didn't know what the separate components of a switch were called and that link helped me figure it out.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background is called a `track` and you can change the color of it by using

`app:trackTint="@color/darkThemeGreyTextColor"`

The "button" is called a `thumb`
and you can change the color of it with

`app:thumbTint="@color/heartRed"`

I didn't see these attributes because I was using the `android:` prefix instead of the `app:` prefix to see the available options.