# Adding frames to images in android

Tags: java, android

I want to create frames for images, can anyone let me know how to add frames to the images which user has selected from gallery or SD card.

Any help will be great full.

Comment: By `frame`, do you mean a simple `border`? Or you want to `overlay` a nice "real-world" (wooden? metallic?) frame?

Comment: real-world @DerGolem

Comment: possible duplicate of [overlay two images in android to set an imageview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview)

Comment: tried but not getting,can anyone help me with the code ?

Comment: See my code, below. Very simple. Tested.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the bitmap from the camera or from the gallery (plenty of docs on this) you should add an overlay using a transparent bitmap.

Also, some useful information when dealing with bitmaps:

http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/bitmap-basics.html